# Use placeholders with <f:all bean />

Tags: grails

In Grails, you can generate a form using `<f:all bean="beanName" />`. And while the generated form looks great, I was wondering if it would be possible to have a placeholder in the field, so that the result becomes something like:

```
<input type="text" name="question" placeholder="type your question here" />
```

I tried using the attributes validation in Grails, like this:

```
class Question {
    static constraints = {
        question(size:5..100, attributes:[placeholder:"type your question here"])
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect on the generated HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case there's any confusion, the `f:all` tag is provided by the fields plugin. I don't think there's any way you can specify the `placeholder` attribute via the domain class constraints, but there are a few other options.

One option is to define a custom (GSP) template for this property and specify the placeholder attribute therein. The path to this template will depend on which version of the plugin you're using, but you can find the details [here](http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html).

Alternatively, if you render each field individually with `f:field`, rather than using `f:all` you can pass additional attributes to the input field, e.g.

```
<f:field bean="person" property="gender" 
        widget-placeholder="type your question here"/>
```

In earlier versions of the plugin (before 1.5), the attribute should be named `input-placeholder` instead, e.g.

```
<f:field bean="person" property="gender" 
        input-placeholder="type your question here"/>
```

Comment: Hi Donal, thanks for your answer. Your first option would work, if all placeholders were the same I guess. But the placeholder depends on the domain attribute. I'm not a fan of using the `<f:field>`, but I have a very simple domain with a great deal of fields, for which `<f:all>` works really nicely. But any idea why the attributes don't work? I assumed they were meant for this...

Comment: You can define a template that will only be applied to an individual domain class property, e.g. `grails-app/views/_fields/person/name/_wrapper.gsp`.

Where in the fields plugin docs does it mention the use of constraints to customise the input fields?

Comment: Hmm, but I need placeholders for all properties, not just for one. That's the same amount of work, maybe even more. And the fields plugin doesn't mention it, but the Grails attributes documentation does: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/attributes.html. It seems to be a nice match.

Comment: According to the grails docs "This constraint only works for boolean (checkbox), date (datePicker), and collection (*select) properties". It seems your property is likely of type `String`